# Following a tag profile doesn't update newsfeed

Tags: newsfeed, tagging

We are using Sharepoint 2013 and when we upload a document and go into its Tags and Notes, we add a keyword: awesome.  I can then click on the tag, go to its profile page, and select 'Follow' so that it appears in my profiles Interests box.  I can go back and create another document and tag it with the same tag, but I don't see anything come through the newsfeed about a document being uploaded with that tag.  Is that not how following a tag profile should work?  Likewise, I post comments to a tag profile and I don't see anything come through on my newsfeed about me posting a comment.  How would a user know to view this tag profile's information if not for the newsfeed?

Here's a screenshot of the tag profile page.  Two documents have been added to the keyword but nothing shows up:

[image]

You can see that comments work just fine, but nothing appears under the tagged items.  In my newsfeed, I see my comments, but nothing about the documents being added to the library using that keyword show up.

**EDIT**
I have continued looking into this and found that if I click the last 60 days, the documents show up.  After digging around on the internet, this makes sense.  Doing a 60 day query is doing a hard object lookup.  Using the All query uses search 100%.  So somewhere along the way, Sharepoint is not crawling Tag Profiles.  I have a content source set up in Search Administration with one URL of sps3://my.sharepoint.domain .  Are there any other URLs that I can add to force the crawl of tag profiles?

**Further EDIT**
After ripping out the search application and reinstalling and waiting a couple days for everything to be indexed, items appear in the Tag Profile page but don't appear in the newsfeed.  After some googling, tags & notes do not appear in the newsfeed.  Only social tags do.

Comment: Clear Cache firstly (IE is a big culprit for that) secondly, check if this isn't instantaneous, may be a part of a scheduled task to check.

Comment: I did a hard refresh in Chrome and see the comment I posted to the tag profile's page.  But no amount of tagging later documents gets picked up.  In fact, the tag profile page doesn't show any documents tagged with that keyword even though I've done it three times.

Comment: It's actually done using the Search functionality of SP2013, is your search functionality working and how often does it run?

Comment: Search is turned on and has been working.  I can see posts to the note board, but I can't see any document that has been added to the keyword.